# Does scikit-learn support plotting calibration curve for multiclass classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, multi-class, calibration

I have trained a multi class classifier and calibrated the classified using scikit-learn library's CalibratedClassifierCV class. To check how well the probabilities are calibrated, I tried plotting the calibration curve using scikit-learn's calibration_curve function. I got this error:

> Only binary classification is supported. Provided labels ['A' 'B' 'C'].

I then read scikit-learn's documentation and got to know that scikitlearn calibration_curve function expects input from a binary classifier. Will scikit-learn be supporting plotting calibration_curve for multiclass classification? Are there any alternative solutions to plot the calibration curve for a multi class classifier?

Comment: [A related post of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/552533/247274) might be of interest. In particular, multi-class calibration is not so straightforward.